# How to change all the black pixels to white (OpenCV)?

Tags: python, opencv, colors, rgb

I am new to OpenCV and I do not understand how to traverse and change all the pixels of black with colour code exact `RGB(0,0,0)` to white colour `RGB(255,255,255)`.
Is there any function or way to check all the pixel and if `RGB(0,0,0)` the make it to `RGB(255,255,255)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your image is represented as a `numpy` array of shape `(height, width, channels)` (what `cv2.imread` returns), you can do:

```py
height, width, _ = img.shape

for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        # img[i, j] is the RGB pixel at position (i, j)
        # check if it's [0, 0, 0] and replace with [255, 255, 255] if so
        if img[i, j].sum() == 0:
            img[i, j] = [255, 255, 255]
```

A faster, mask-based approach looks like this:

```py
# get (i, j) positions of all RGB pixels that are black (i.e. [0, 0, 0])
black_pixels = np.where(
    (img[:, :, 0] == 0) & 
    (img[:, :, 1] == 0) & 
    (img[:, :, 2] == 0)
)

# set those pixels to white
img[black_pixels] = [255, 255, 255]
```

Comment: Although correct I think this would be painfully slow, you should use numpy with for example: `img[np.where((img==[0,0,0]).all(axis=2))] = [255,255,255]`. Ah, you've done it, sorry

Answer (score 0):

**Subtract 255 from each Pixel and get the positive values only**

For grayscale and black and white images

`sub_array = 255*np.ones(28, dtype = int)`
`img_Invert = np.abs(np.subtract(img,sub_array))`

Answer (score -1):

```
cv.rectangle(img,(0,0),(img.shape[1],img.shape[0],(255,255,255),thickness=-1)
cv.imshow('img',img)
```

Comment: Where is the explanation?  Where is the formatting? This is an old page, there is no reason to rush your answer.